# How can I scroll down to the bottom of document (HTML) in Safari?

Tags: keyboard, safari

I normally can use Command-DownArrow, to go to the bottom of the document in text editor such as TextMate.

How can I do the same thing in Safari? How can I scroll down to the bottom of the document with Safari when I read the long HTML document?

And, how can I scroll one screen with keyboard?

Comment: Command+Down works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Down ↓</kbd> or <kbd>Function (Fn)</kbd> + <kbd>Right →</kbd> should both work.

<kbd>Fn Right</kbd> is the built-in key combination that is most equivalent to the <kbd>End</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

> And, how can I scroll one screen with keyboard?

Press the <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

Comment: that only scrolls a couple lines and does not jump to the bottom of the page tho...

Comment: Strange. On my computer it scrolls one screen.